# android- listview inside a drawerlayout would disappear sometimes

Tags: android, listview, android-support-library, drawerlayout

I have several listviews in my app and one of them is inside of the drawerlayout. what happen is the listview inside of the drawer would disppear sometimes randomly. all other listviews are working fine. does anyone have the same problem? my guess is the supported library not reliable because I saw some discussions online about the issues with supported libraries. but since i have no clue on how to reproduce it, i cant really tell if the issue was from supported library.

Comment: It is impossible for anything to give valuable feedback in this case without seeing any code.

Comment: @user1865027 could you show how you bind the ListView to the UI and how the adapter is bonded to the listview(if you have done it). If so also show the constructor of the adapter

Comment: Im sorry. I understand its kind of hard to tell what the real problem is without seeing the actual code, but cz the code is confidential, i cant provide the actual code here. but my listview is basically similar as all other tutorials online(and the same as all other working listviews in the app). i asked cz i know there are several known issues with support library like `onActivityResult` not called within the fragment. [example here](https://gist.github.com/artem-zinnatullin/6916740) I was just wondering if others have encountered the same issue with listview in drawer